# How to serve images with a dokku application and nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, local-storage, dokku

I am new with dokku and nginx.
I want to serve images from my server, right now I have an application running in dokku serving me different json from a database. Right now I want to upload files and images and serve that images to the users.

- I could find some [documentation](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/blob/master/docs/advanced-usage/persistent-storage.md) about dokku persistent storage, to mount a local storage and redirect all the data from the application to that directory.
- My question right now is. How can I serve the image to the users? If I user http://app-name.host.com/storage/image-url.jpg it will do the trick?.
- Or should I use some configuration from the nginx file to serve the files directly from the server local storage?

Maybe someone could guide me in the right path because I can not find any clear information about that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- ship a customized [nginx.conf.sigil](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/configuration/nginx/#customizing-the-nginx-configuration) with your repository to make the external nginx route to the storage directory directly
- modify your application to serve it. Most frameworks have this functionality.

Comment: Thank you Jose for the response. I was investigating and the framework that I am using have the option to create in the container a folder to upload and download images, so with that and mounting a persistent storage (and linking to the container folder) could be posible to persist data into my server?

Comment: That is correct, the persistent storage plugin will allow you to mount a directory into the container.

Comment: Thank you for your help!